# PrincipalPermission always fails

Tags: c#, .net, security, authorization

I'm really confused, what should be passes as a `User` attribute to `PrincipalPermission` decorator. I just created brand new WPF application, in .NET 4.6.1 (but I also tried 4.5.2 and 4.0), I put a one button with a click event:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "MYDOMAIN\\myusername")]
private void foo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name; // this returns: MYDOMAIN\\myusername
}
```

I'm getting **Request for principal permission failed**. Why??

I also tried:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "myusername")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "sysadmin")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "DEVELOPERS")]
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Administrators")]
```

I even tried:
`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]`

It just doesn't work.. what am I doing wrong? I have VS2015 if that matters.

**EDIT:**

Let me simplify it even more:

- New WPF app (.NET 4.6.1, VS2017, Windows7)
- one button with even-click:

  ```
  private void foo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      Test();
  }

  public bool Test()
  {
      try
      {
          var userName = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
          var group = GetGroups(userName).FirstOrDefault();

          var p = new PrincipalPermission(userName, group);
          p.Demand();
      }
      catch (SecurityException)
      {
          throw;
      }
      return true;
  }

  private static String[] GetGroups(string userName)
  {
      var toReturn = new List<String>();
      using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
      using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, userName))
      {
          if (user != null)
          {
              var output = user.GetGroups().Select(x => x.SamAccountName).ToArray();

              foreach (var group in output)
                  toReturn.Add(group);
          }
      }
      return toReturn.ToArray();
  }
  ```

Whyyy?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to restrict a method to a *group* called `GroupA`, you can use

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "GroupA")]
```

note the use of `PrincipalPermission.Role` instead of `PrincipalPermission.Name`. Do you have a *group* called `username`? I think not, and that might likely be the issue. I'm not sure whether you can restrict methods to a single user name, I only know of restricting for user groups.

---

The only usage of `PrincipalPermission.Name` I know of is if you make use of a certificate, e.g.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "CN=<SubjectName>; <Certificate Thumbprint>")]
```

Comment: I think you can use "Name" as username, without the certificate. But anyway..  groups don't work for me either. I tried every group I'm on :/